# jQuery .slideToggle – Somehow being triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Here's my code, I've tried to cut anything unnecessary from the JS:
http://codepen.io/Zacaree/pen/EmZJXy

When I click one of the dropdown buttons (right side of page) triggering jQuery's .slideToggle, it opens a drawer but instead of remaining open, the drawer will trigger multiple times. The number of times triggered increases with each successive panel down the page.

The uppermost panel always works correctly.

```
function foo() {    
    $('.dashboard-right').children('h1').after(functionContainer).siblings('.function-container').removeClass('isPaused');

    $('.dropdown-button').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.function-footer').siblings('.log-container').slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).children('.arrow').toggleClass('active');
    });
};

foo();
foo();
foo();
foo();
foo();
```

I'm a designer not a developer so please forgive me for posting what's probably a simple error on my part. I've fought and fought with this and can't seem to figure it out. Thank you so much to anyone who can explain to me what I'm doing wrong!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding a click event every single time `foo` is called (Since the method is called 5 times, 5 click events are being bound to that element )

You need to just bind the click event only once.

Move the click binding event to outside of the `foo` method.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvpLeg

```
function foo() {    
    $('.dashboard-right').children('h1')
                        .after(functionContainer)
                        .siblings('.function-container')
                        .removeClass('isPaused');
  };

$('body').on('click', '.dropdown-button' ,function() {
      $(this).parents('.function-footer')
             .siblings('.log-container')
             .slideToggle('fast');

      $(this).children('.arrow').toggleClass('active');
});

  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
  foo();
```

Comment: Most of that makes sense to me, could you explain why
`$('.dropdown-button').click(function(){`
doesn't work outside of foo()?

In other words, why does it have to be 
`$('body').on('click', '.dropdown-button' ,function()`

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zacaree That is because the element is not yet present in the DOM when you bind the events. This is called event delegation where you bind the event to the closest parent container and let the event bubble to which it is bound. You could either do this or `$('.dropdown-button').click(function(){` after calling `foo` 5 times which makes sure the event is present in the DOM before binding it.